# ORA-01466: unable to read data - table definition has changed

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

What happen when is done a import from a export with this erro?
I have a table that every day is altered the structure during the consistent export (flashback_time=systimestamp) and I always receive this erro. If I to do a import using this export, it will work well?

Comment: Try it and see what happens?

Comment: It's a production environment, but I did the a test here. The table is imported with the structure modifications, but no data is loaded in the table..